# TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable on Windows 10 Bash

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to install matplotlib on Windows 10 Bash shell.

After that, I ran following lines:

```
$ ipython3
```

then

```
In[1]: %pylab
```

then it gives me a following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4ab7ec3413a5> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic('pylab')

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in magic(self, arg_s)
   2164         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2165         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2166         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2167
   2168     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2085                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2086             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2087                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2088             return result
   2089

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py in pylab(self, line)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    190     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    191     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 192         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    193
    194         if isinstance(arg, collections.Callable):

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py in pylab(self, line)
    129             import_all = not args.no_import_all
    130
--> 131         gui, backend, clobbered = self.shell.enable_pylab(args.gui, import_all=import_all)
    132         self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
    133         print ("Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib")

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in enable_pylab(self, gui, import_all, welcome_message)
   2918         from IPython.core.pylabtools import import_pylab
   2919
-> 2920         gui, backend = self.enable_matplotlib(gui)
   2921
   2922         # We want to prevent the loading of pylab to pollute the user's

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   2879                 gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(self.pylab_gui_select)
   2880
-> 2881         pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
   2882         pt.configure_inline_support(self, backend)
   2883

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in activate_matplotlib(backend)
    244     matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = backend
    245
--> 246     import matplotlib.pyplot
    247     matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend(backend)
    248

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>()
   2510 # are no-ops and the registered function respect `mpl.is_interactive()`
   2511 # to determine if they should trigger a draw.
-> 2512 install_repl_displayhook()
   2513
   2514 ################# REMAINING CONTENT GENERATED BY boilerplate.py ##############

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in install_repl_displayhook()
    163             ipython_gui_name = backend2gui.get(get_backend())
    164             if ipython_gui_name:
--> 165                 ip.enable_gui(ipython_gui_name)
    166         else:
    167             _INSTALL_FIG_OBSERVER = True

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py in enable_gui(gui, app)
    306         from IPython.lib.inputhook import enable_gui as real_enable_gui
    307         try:
--> 308             return real_enable_gui(gui, app)
    309         except ValueError as e:
    310             raise UsageError("%s" % e)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/lib/inputhook.py in enable_gui(gui, app)
    526         e = "Invalid GUI request %r, valid ones are:%s" % (gui, list(guis.keys()))
    527         raise ValueError(e)
--> 528     return gui_hook(app)
    529

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/lib/inputhook.py in enable_tk(self, app)
    322         if app is None:
    323             import tkinter
--> 324             app = tkinter.Tk()
    325             app.withdraw()
    326             self._apps[GUI_TK] = app

/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py in __init__(self, screenName, baseName, className, useTk, sync, use)
   1852                 baseName = baseName + ext
   1853         interactive = 0
-> 1854         self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
   1855         if useTk:
   1856             self._loadtk()

TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I'd appreciate if anybody can point out how to remove this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

There is no official display environment for bash on Windows.

- You need to install unoffical display environment, i.e. xming (https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/)
- After installing xming you need to export as **DISPLAY=:0**.
- You also need to install qtconsole. **sudo apt-get install qtconsole**

However, I don't suggest going in this way, there is a much easier way for using ipython on Windows. You can install Anaconda on Windows and you can use ipython without any problems like this (https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Comment: Thank you so much! After trying with your suggestion I'll select your answer.

Comment: Anaconda is easy to install and easy to use. After installing anaconda you will have ipython. You can run ipython either going to Start and typing ipython or you can use cmd and run ipython. Either way works fine.

Comment: Can you please explain how can I do the second step?

Comment: On bash terminal type DISPLAY=:0

Comment: Thanks! In the third step, it returns "Unable to locate package qtconsole"

Comment: So I've installed python-qtconsole and python3-qtconsole, but I am getting the same error

Comment: You have to install qtconsole itself, i.e. third step. Why don't you use Anaconda which is more easier?

Comment: I didn't need to do the third step, then to do step 2 enter `export DISPLAY=:0.0`.